# I have a TypeError in Python

Tags: python, typeerror

```
from Abstractions.Products import Products
from itertools import product
from Implementation.ProductsImplementation import ProductsImplementation
from Implementation.VendorImplementation import VendorImplementation
from Models.VendorSessionModel import VendorSessionModel

if __name__ == '__main__':


    vendor = VendorImplementation()
    username = input("Enter vendor name:")
    password = input("Enter your password:")
    login_res = vendor.login(username, password)
    if login_res == False:
        print("Not authorized Vendor")
    else:
        products = ProductsImplementation(username)
        print("Enter Number of product you want to add:")
        p = Products()
        n= int(input())
        
        for i in range(1, n+1):
            product_name = input("Please Enter Product Name:")
            product_type = input("Please Enter product type:")
            available_quantity = input("Please enter avilable quantity:")
            unit_price = input("please enter unit price:")
            
            p.add_product()
```

Products Class code

```
class Products:

    def add_product(self, product_name, product_type, available_quantity, unit_price):
        """This abstract method will be used to add products"""
        pass
```

ProductsImplementation class code

```
class ProductsImplementation(Products):
    def __init__(self, username):
        self.product_model = ProductModel()
        self.vendor_session = VendorSessionModel()
        self._username = username

    def add_product(self, product_name, product_type, available_quantity, unit_price):
        if not self.vendor_session.check_login(self._username):
            print("please login first")
            return False
        self.product_model.add_product(product_name,product_type,available_quantity,unit_price)
        print(product_name + "added sucessfully")
```

Below is the error I get when I try to run this

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "e:\psython_project\M01-W01-02-Ecommerce_vendor_management\Driver.py", line 28, in <module>
    p.add_product()
TypeError: Products.add_product() missing 4 required positional arguments: 'product_name', 'product_type', 'available_quantity', and 'unit_price'**
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You forgot to provide the arguments to the `add_product` method. Change the last line to:

```
p.add_product(product_name, product_type, available_quantity, unit_price)
```

Comment: Can you mark the question answered if it is correct?

Comment: sure..............